# Connection refused using Dashing with Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, apache, raspberry-pi, hosts, dashing

I've looked everywhere and can't find an elegant solution to this.

I'm trying to run Dashing on a Raspberry Pi - and I'm having problems connecting to the dashboard.

Dashing logs say:

```
Listening on 0.0.0.0:3030
```

However, my localhost IP is 127.0.0.1.

Trying to connect via localhost:3030/sample *or* 127.0.0.1:3030/sample *or* 0.0.0.0:3030/sample all fail with a (146) Connection Refused.

Pinging localhost/0.0.0.0 both re-route to 127.0.0.1.

I can however connect when I use my network IP address - found using

```
hostname -I
```

It works as expected. However, this isn't really a great solution as this IP address may change next time I reboot the Pi.

I am using a proxy, which is defined in both the /etc/environment and /pi/home/.profile files. However, I can't see why that should make a difference.

If anybody might have any clues about this - I'd appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using the hostname itself which should not change. If bonjour is available you ma also be able to do raspberrypi.local:3030/sample. Alternatively you could set a static IP as suggested by hcheung below or reserve an IP via your router.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. The hostname IP does work - it's the only way I can see the dashboard - although with a reboot, the router will assign a new IP address (out of my control) and the link to it is lost without running `hostname-I`. I have to hand this over to someone else, so ideally I want the address to stay static. Bonjour is installed, but pinging raspberrypi.local on the pi itself doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Dashing, but my spontaneous reaction is why don't you just assign a static network ip to the Raspberry Pi by adding something like following codes to the /etc/dhcpcd.conf:

```
   interface eth0
   static ip_address=192.168.0.101/24
   static routers=192.168.0.1
```

Will that solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - sorry for the slow response, I've left it over Christmas. Unfortunately, running it like this prevents connection to the internet. I think my network (uncontrolled by me unfortunately) is forcing the IP address out of my control. I'm starting to think ensuring that localhost IP is 0.0.0.0 for all might be the only solution, but I'm struggling to manage that with any guides I've found online.